# Prevent flutter web cuts off the url path #

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

My flutter web site is redirected from another site with the format like this:

```
 http://example.com/#id_token=abc
```

I'd like to read the info in `#id_token=abc` in `initState` like this

```
 @override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var url = html.window.location.href;
    if (url.contains('id_token=')) {
       // read data
    }
 }
```

But the flutter site is reloaded & cut off `#id_token` part automatically (the same for localhost when debugging) before it goes to `initState`, the new url is

```
http://example.com/#/
```

It makes my code can't read the `id_token` info correctly
It looks weird, how can I prevent this happen? 
P/s: it works well with the url paramter format like http://example.com?id_token=abc but **I can't control other site** to support this format

Comment: It's because flutter uses hash based navigation. If the page is not exists it replaces it with root uri `/#/`. Check out that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33245

Comment: @MisirJafarov So basically there is no way to handle my case?

Comment: I haven't used flutter for web. You may try to implement url navigation (if you haven't) then check if hashes are working or not. https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/ed5mq9/advance_url_navigation_for_flutter_web/

Comment: I have the same problem using supabase with gotrue, which returns a baseUrl/#accessToken url.
Flutter just cuts everything after #, on mobile and web as well.
I am using Navigator 2.0/Router. Changing the url strategy on web to not use a baseUrl/#/ does not help.
@R4j have you found a solution?

Comment: @nstrelow sorry for late, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any solution on flutter side. 
So I solve my problem by using a blank page and use javascript to read data from `#id_token=abc` and then navigates to flutter home page with parameter like this `index.html?id_token=abc` 
Here is the page content:

```
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      console.log('document is ready');
      var url = window.location.href;
      console.log(url);
      if(url.indexOf('#id_token=') != -1){
        var idToken = url.split('#id_token=')[1];
        console.log('idToken ' + idToken);
        window.location.replace("index.html?id_token=" + idToken);
      }else {
        console.log('there is no id token');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
<div class="center-screen">Waiting...</div>
```

Update: there is an official way from flutter to set path strategy
[here](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-the-url-strategy)

```
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(ExampleApp());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is quite strange. I have no problem getting it to work for Web. Where it cuts off is on Android and iOS, where I've already raised the issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80666